# c# how to update dynamically generated label at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C#, I'm trying to update values in dynamically generated label when I press button. But it doesn't overwrite the label on form.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int b = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label label = new Label(); // used to print users

            label.Text = String.Format("{0}", b);

            label.Left = 10;
            label.Top =  25;
            this.Controls.Add(label);

            b = b + 1;

            Console.WriteLine(b);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to update a label or create a new one every time you click the button? Right now you're creating a new one every time.

Comment: @itsme86 I want to remove the previous label and create new one with updated value

Comment: This begs the question....why don't you just update the text of the existing label?

Comment: I agree with @itsme86 about updating the label. As to why your new label does not seems to appear - controls added later to the form have lower Z-value than controls added before them, which means the first label with the value `0` hides all of the others behind it.

Comment: @itsme86 Ok, if I generate for example say 10 labels on form in a column, and insert values in it, then I want to remove 4th label...how can I do that?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Are you against using a ListBox for that?

Answer (score 1):

Why remove the old one instead of update it? Once updated, the outcome is the same. There is a lot that goes into intializing a Forms control, see InitializeComponent(). You'd be much better off changing the Text property of the label you have already.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLabelsDesignName.Text = String.Format("{0}", b);


        b = b + 1;

        Console.WriteLine(b);

    }
```

Comment: Ok, if I generate for example say 10 labels on form in a column, and insert values in it, then I want to remove 4th label...how can I do that?

Comment: This is a very vague question but I'll do my best. For generation, you should use the form designer to position all the labels you will ever anticipate needing whre you anticipate needing them. This will genrate all the auto-generated code to initialize them. Make sure you give them a DesignName. Then in your cs code, you can simply change the Visible property accordingly depending on whether you want a given label to be seen.

Comment: in this case the sender is a button, and presumably not the label to change.  So instead of casting sender to Label to get his label reference he needs a way to reference the particular label.

Comment: Ahh, yes you're right. Referencing design name should do the trick. editing now

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want, you need a way to reference the previous label. You can do that using the same approach you used to keep track of `b`:

```
int b = 1;
Label labelOnForm;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (labelOnForm != null)
    {
       this.Controls.Remove(labelOnForm);
       labelOnForm.Dispose();
    }

    Label label = new Label(); // used to print users
    label.Text = String.Format("{0}", b);

    label.Left = 10;
    label.Top =  25;
    this.Controls.Add(label);

    labelOnForm = label;

    b = b + 1;

    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

However, you can simply update the existing label instead of creating a new one every time:

```
int b = 1;
Label labelOnForm;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (labelOnForm == null)  // label doesn't exist yet
    {
        Label label = new Label(); // used to print users

        label.Left = 10;
        label.Top =  25;
        this.Controls.Add(label);

        labelOnForm = label;
    }

    labelOnForm.Text = String.Format("{0}", b);

    b = b + 1;

    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```